# How can I avoid <input file> deletes values after selecting files?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm working on a web uploader, however, I found something, I do not know if it's a problem. This is what I found:

When I choose files with  `<input type="file" multiple>`, the values ​​of all selected files are stored in a list of files which is within the INPUT. However, when I add more files, the files that I select replace those I selected previously. I think this is a default behavior of this element DOM.

**What do I have to do if I want to add more files without deleting my chosen before?**

Does anyone know how to do this?

Btw: Sorry for my bad english, It's not my mother language.Thanks.

Comment: You can access `input.files` to get an array of the files selected. You could store the list on each change in another array, so that you end up with all files ever selected. But you cannot combine these arrays to set the input value - do you need the actual input element?

Comment: I don't think so. However, i believe  '<input type="file">' is necessary for sending data to a php.file in order to upload files. Or can i do it with an array,too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of all `FileList`s, and loop over each one when sending through ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/46Pk8/. However, keep in mind that you can select (and upload) a file more than once this way. A better method would be to have a visual list, and let the user be able to add/remove files to/from the list.

```
var files = [];  // this will contain FileLists

$("button:first").on("click", function(e) {
    $("<input>").prop({
        "type": "file",
        "multiple": true
    }).on("change", function(e) {
        files.push(this.files);
    }).trigger("click");
});

$("button:last").on("click", function(e) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/echo/html/", true);
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function() {  // each FileList
        $.each(this, function() {  // each file inside this list
            console.log("appending %s", this.name);
            data.append("files", this);
        });
    });
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("done");
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be honest, there are some parts of your code you do not understand, but I know this is the answer. Finally, there remains only the problem of how to remove items from the list of files before uploading. I will study the code to understand it more. Once again many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can insert *another* `input` after file choose and hide original one.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm just learning how to handle DOM elements, how can I create another "<input type=file>" after selecting files and then hide the previous one?

I am very grateful for your response.

Comment: When user chooses a file, event `onchange` fires. You should set event handler for it. So when user chooses a file, you can hide that input, create another one (via `document.createElement`, for example) and insert it right. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9x9mV/