# Checking multiple files

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a file element, and a button that allows a user to add more file elements so that if they wanted to, they could select multiple at once.  I want to be able to loop through them and need some assistance as to what direction I should take or if there is a correct syntax to do this.  Form, php, and JS code below.

Form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP']);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_form" id="upload_form">
<br />
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file"/>
<input id="addbutton" type="button" onclick = 'javascript: add()' value="ADD ANOTHER FILE" />
<br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "SUBMIT")
{
$count = count($_FILES[ "file" ][ "tmp_name" ]);
echo $count;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
{
        if($_FILES && $_FILES['file']['name'])
        {
            //code that does some stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
function add()
{
    var form = document.getElementById("upload_form");
    var addButton = document.getElementById('addbutton');

    var br = document.createElement("br");
    form.insertBefore(br, addButton);

    form = document.getElementById("upload_form");

    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type="file";
    input.name="file[]";
    form.insertBefore(input, addButton);
}
```

Comment: I sound familiar to me! Check a question that I made a few month ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793328/how-can-i-avoid-input-file-deletes-values-after-selecting-files  and this one,too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552172/problems-with-handling-arrays-gotten-from-php-by-using-jquery-ajax . Maybe they can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every thing is looks ok, u just need to add index to access particully uploaded file like

```
   <?php

   // ...
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
    {
        echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
     // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  For some reason I was thinking that it needed to look like $_FILES['file['.$i.']']['tmp_name['.$i.']']

Comment: i want to recoment to u using of echo '<pre>'; print_r( $var ); 
 or  echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $var ); to look what inside your variable
 it's very useful

Answer (score 0):

Looks perfect, but you can just use this for multiple selection:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

You won't need that javascript...