# fileinput jquery plugin multiple file selection from different directory

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using fileinput.min.js and am giving the class for file upload control as "file-input".

When I select a file and click open, It will select that file and show in the UI. Now I will again click on browse and select different file and click on open, old selection is lost.

Can anyone help me by guiding where i need to do the changes so that i can retain the old selected file also?

This is my aspx code

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" CssClass="file-input"/>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793328/how-can-i-avoid-input-file-deletes-values-after-selecting-files Looks like this answers your question.